# Is the memory in std::array contiguous?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++11, contiguous

Is the memory in `std::array` contiguous? Is the following valid/good practice?

```
std::array<type1,Num> arr = //initialize value
type1 * ptr = &arr[0];
```

Could I then pass `ptr` to functions expecting a c-style array?

Comment: Yes, I did. Thanks for finding that.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, it is contiguous, as it is basically (and actually) a `type arr[10];`, but with STL like interface. It also doesn't decay to a pointer on the slightest provocation.

You can safely pass `&arr[0]` to a function expecting a C-style array, that's the design goal of it. To use it with the STL algorithms however, just use the `begin` and `end` functions:

```
// either members
std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
// or free from <iterator>
std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
```

---

For the language lawyer part, `§23.3.2.1 [array.overview] p1`:

> The header `<array>` defines a class template for storing fixed-size sequences of objects. An array supports random access iterators. An instance of `array<T, N>` stores `N` elements of type `T`, so that `size() == N` is an invariant. **The elements of an `array` are stored contiguously**, meaning that if `a` is an `array<T, N>` then it obeys the identity `&a[n] == &a[0] + n` for all `0 <= n < N`.

And `§23.3.2.1 [array.overview] p2`:

> An array is an aggregate (8.5.1) that can be initialized with the syntax
>
> - `array<T, N> a = {` *initializer-list* `};`

Also, in `p3`, listing the members of `std::array`:

> `T elems[N]; // exposition only`
> [ *Note:* The member variable `elems` is shown for exposition only, to emphasize that `array` is a class aggregate. The name `elems` is not part of `array`’s interface. *—end note* ]

Comment: The standard explicitly states that `std::vector` shall have contiguous memory allocation, Similar is the case with std::array?

Comment: @Als: First, I get notified of comments to my answer anyways, second, yes. :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does that quote from the standard explicitly require that `std::array<_T, _N>` be implemented under-the-hood as `_T arr[_N]`?? Not that it's a good idea, but what's to stop me having a `std::array` class that allocates a correctly sized `std::vector` behind the scenes and prevents any resizing?? As I said, I'm NOT suggesting this would be a good idea.

Comment: @Darren The requirement that `std::array` be an aggregate.

Comment: @Xeo, Luc: good, looks like they've got all bases covered... :)

Comment: Why use `arr.begin()` and `arr.end()` in preference to `begin(arr)` and `end(arr)`? I find it slightly amusing that C++0x finally adds a container-style interface to an automatic array, at the same time as finally introducing a concept of a single object that represents a range, so that we no longer need an array to have a container-style interface ;-)

Comment: @Steve: I do so, because *I can*. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Yes the memory of `std::array` is contiguous. On VC10, it is declared as:

```
template<class _Ty,
    size_t _Size>
    class array
    { // fixed size array of values
                ... 
         _Ty _Elems[_Size == 0 ? 1 : _Size];
    };
```

Where `_Elemes` is nothing but a simple array of given type.

Comment: This is merely one implementation of `std::array`. Your answer is correct, but your justification is invalid. Other implementations could write the class differently. The reason they can't is because it would violate the specification. You forgot to mention that.

Comment: May be, buy GNU implementation uses same approach: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.3/a01741.html