# Is the data in nested std::arrays guaranteed to be contiguous?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, c++11

Is the data in `std::array<std::array<T,N>, M>` guaranteed to be contiguous? For example:

```
#include <array>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    enum {M=4, N=7};
    typedef std::array<char,N> Row;
    typedef std::array<Row, M> Matrix;
    Matrix a;
    a[1][0] = 42;
    const char* data = a[0].data();

    /* 8th element of 1D data array should be the same as
       1st element of second row. */
    assert(data[7] == 42);
}
```

Is the assert guaranteed to succeed? Or, to put it another way, can I rely on there being no padding at the end of a `Row`?

**EDIT:** Just to be clear, for this example, I want the data of the **entire matrix** to be contiguous.

Comment: Even if the storage is contiguous, I believe you would be falling foul of aliasing rules.  See this question I asked many moons ago (about C, admittedly): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290956/one-dimensional-access-to-a-multidimensional-array-well-defined-c.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the memory in std::array contiguous?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632915/is-the-memory-in-stdarray-contiguous) by recursion

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : No, I don't think it's a duplicate. While the data in a single `std::array` is contiguous, that doesn't imply that the entire set of data in nested `std::array`s is contiguous. Or at least it's not obvious to a non-language lawyer like me.

Comment: @Emile: Yes, it does. If every element in an `std::array` is contiguous, then that means every `std::array` in an `std::array<std::array<..>>` is directly next to the next one. And, by recursion, each of those "sub"-`std::array`s are contiguous, too. A container doesn't suddenly and magically lose contiguousness (if, indeed, that's a guarantee of the container) just because it's its own `value_type`. _[edit: However, that is not the same as the inner-most `T`s all being contiguous to one another. Seems that's what you meant after all, so, fine :P]_

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : Like James said in his answer, there is no requirement that there be no padding or extra data members at the end of an `array<T>`, though I admit that decent implementations would not do such a thing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, contiguity is not guaranteed in this case.

`std::array` is guaranteed to be an aggregate, and is specified in such a way that the underlying array used for storage must be the first data member of the type.

However, there is no requirement that `sizeof(array<T, N>) == sizeof(T) * N`, nor is there any requirement that there are no unnamed padding bytes at the end of the object or that `std::array` has no data members other than the underlying array storage.  (Though, an implementation that included additional data members would be, at best, unusual.)

Answer (score 5):

They are very likely contiguous. If they are not, the compiler is actively fighting you there. There's no guarantee it won't insert padding but there's hardly a reason for it.

> Is the assert guaranteed to succeed?

`data[7]` is an out-of-bounds access (undefined behaviour). The inner array object has only seven elements, so index 7 is not valid.

Comment: Hmm, your answer seems a bit contradictory (or I'm just too dense). If the data is contiguous, wouldn't `data[7]` point to the first element of the second row?

Comment: @Emile the flaw in thinking "8th element of 1D data array should be the same as 1st element of second row." is ignoring that no array in that code has an 8th element. There's no guarantee as to what `data[7]` will do because of that. In practice, yes, I suspect it will point to the first element of the second row, but as it always is with UB, *you can't safely rely on it*.

Comment: Ok, then I take "*they are very likely contiguous*" to mean that the data in **each inner array** is contiguous. Is this what you meant?

Comment: And each inner array is also contiguous with each other. But when indexing you can't cross from one to the other. It's not a `std::array` thing. The same is true for `int x[4][7]; int* xp = x; xp[7];`. With "they are very likely contiguous" I meant that no sane compiler will insert any padding.

Comment: I'm not saying that's false, but it sure seems counter-intuitive to me. If `int x[4][7]` is contiguous, then that means (to me) that the data occupies 28 consecutive slots of `sizeof(int)` bytes in memory. If I do `xp[7]` (which is equivalent to `*(xp+7)`), then it should just dereference the 8th slot in those 28 consecutive slots. Is indexing different than pointer arithmetic followed by dereferencing?

Comment: @Emile Yes, it will *have the same memory layout* as one big array object with 28 elements (like `int x[28]`). But there is no "one big array with 28 elements". There is one array with 4 elements and four arrays with 7 elements. It will probably work, but the standard gives no guarantees.

Comment: Yes, indexing is pointer arithmetic followed by dereferencing. But `xp+7` is the one-past-the-end pointer of the first inner array, which is not dereferenceable.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightening clarifications. :-)

Comment: @Emile: Just to be clear, and getting back to your original question: I wouldn't mind relying on there being no padding (I don't want to support a compiler that does crazy stuff like that!), because it can actually be tested: `static_assert(sizeof(Matrix) == sizeof(char)*M*N, "nested std::arrays should have no padding");`. I am more weary of relying on indexing as one big array, because that can't be tested (it may work now and usually does, but may fail later when the optimizer decides to take advantage of it to optimize).