# Can I use std::vector<std::vector<T>> to represent two dimensional arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I recently learned how to do two- and three-dimensional arrays in plain C using pointers, however being a C++ enthusiast, I'd also like to figure out how to do multi-dimensional arrays in C++.

I know that the preferred way of doing one-dimensional arrays in C++ is to use `std::vector<T>`, but what about two- and three-dimensional arrays? Would they be represented as `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` and `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T>>>`?

Comment: Sure you can do that. But IMHO using a 1D vector with [proper indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) (e.g., column major or row major order) is more sufficient.

Comment: Yes. This is an array of arrays, so a 2D array. And you could do a 3D array the same way.

Comment: That is one way to do it, but it has the significant drawback that, unlike a normal 2D array, each row is not constrained to be the same length. Another way to do it would be to write a class that internally uses a 1D vector, overloads array operators (mainly just `[]`), and handles get/set operations with row- or column-major ordering.

Comment: I would risk great wrath in suggesting the preferred method of array representation is arguably `std::array<>` unless you *need* heap-storage and/or dynamic sizing. Regardless, yes a vector of vectors (of vectors...) will "work".

Comment: Another possible drawback is that the elements are not contiguous. This may make interfacing to libraries that use single blocks of data for multi-dimensional arrays difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you may use class std::vector to simulate arrays. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    size_t n;
    size_t m;

    std::cout << "Enter the number of rows: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    std::cout << "Enter the number of columns: ";
    std::cin >> m;

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v( n, std::vector<int>( m ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Also consider using of the combination of std::vector with std::array when the number of columns is a compile time constant.

A definition of so-called 3-dimensional array can look as for example

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> 
    v( 2, std::vector<std::vector<int>>( 3, std::vector<int>( 4 ) ) );
```

A more interesting example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

int main() 
{
    size_t n;
    size_t m;

    std::cout << "Enter the number of rows: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    std::cout << "Enter the number of columns: ";
    std::cin >> m;

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v( n, std::vector<int>( m ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        std::iota( v[i].begin(), v[i].end(), i * m );
    }

    for ( const auto &v1 : v )
    {
        for ( auto x : v1 ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter 3 and 5 correspondingly for n and m then the output will be

```
0 1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 9 
10 11 12 13 14
```

Comment: Wow, initializing it is really tricky. Do you know how the initialization would look in 3 dimensional case?

Comment: You're too clever Vlad. Get out of here! :) THX!

Answer (score 3):

While you can technically do that, it is a better idea to use a single `std::vector<T>` and calculate the offsets by hand. The resulting memory layout will be much more cache-friendly, since everything will be tightly packed together and can be traversed sequentially or indexed with no indirection.

However, if C++11 is an option and the size of your array is fixed at compile-time, you should use nested `std::array`s. Dynamic allocation can be easily achieved with `std::unique_ptr`. Note however that the data won't necessarily be strictly contiguous between sub-arrays, which could be a problem when interfacing with API's expecting a single ol' block of data.

Comment: Note that an `std::array` of `std::array` is not guaranteed to have all elements contiguous. So a single `std::array` with clever indexing would be a better option.

Comment: @juanchopanza True, but even though the `std::array` headers (size and so on) will get squeezed in-between data, the difference won't even be noticeable, expecially compared to the cost of a cache miss on each element from nested `std::vector`s. And with nested `std::array`s you get neat `operator[]`s straight out of the box.

Comment: There's no need for data members like size, but there could be some padding, and the standard allows for extra space at the end. But the issue is that the elements aren't contiguous like they are in a plain C-style 2D array, and this has implications if you need to use, say, high performance linear algebra libraries that expect a single block of data.

Comment: @juanchopanza of course there's no size member, it's a template parameter... one "duh" moment for me. The external library argument holds, I'm adding it up there.

Comment: I do not see how nested `std::array`s will ever look any different than multidimensional native arrays memory layout wise. Can someone give an example of that mysterious padding actually manifesting? I thought `std::array` was specifically made to work with API's expecting a continuous block of memory.

Comment: @nwp well, it's just [next door](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9762712/3233393). But as said answer states, it would ba a bit weird to implement `std::array`with padding, but still standard-compliant. That's in such cases that I usually trust the implementation not to do weird things, and drop in a `static_assert()` to be warned if it ever changes.

Answer (score 1):

Sure!

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    typedef std::vector<double> VD;
    typedef std::vector<VD>    VVD;

    // 10x5 matrix filled with ones
    VVD mtx(10, VD(5, 1));

    std::cout << mtx.size() << " " << mtx[0].size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << mtx[3][2] << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Amazing, I love that I can use `mtx[3][2]` so easily. THX!