# Best practice for allocating a continuous 2d array on the heap using c++14

Tags: c++, c++14

I am having a hard time finding the answer to the following:

What is the best practice way of allocating a 2d array of ints that is contiguous in memory on the heap in c++14.

Conditions:

- The width and height is known at compile time but I would still like to put the 2d array on the heap for various reasons.
- I would like to access memory locations using the 2d syntax arr[x][y]
- I do not want to implement my own wrapper if possible

Sub questions:

- Do I have to use std::array or is the native int[][dim] syntax usable?
- Is it possible to have a unique_ptr to the 2d array?

Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec(n, std::vector<int>(m));` If the size is known at compile-time, please do not use dynamic memory.

Comment: @DeiDei That will not be contiguous and will be quite inefficient. As for your second sentence, that's just wrong.

Comment: `auto &arr = *new std::array<std::array<TYPE, height>, width>`? Or `std::vector<std::array<TYPE, height>> arr(width);`?

Comment: @DeiDei you suggest to use `std::vector` and you suggest not to use `std::vector`?

Comment: Use a `std::vector<int>` and calculate the offset for every access. Remove requirement three and adapt requirement two so that the syntax of your wrapper class becomes `arr(x, y)`.

Comment: "on the heap for various reasons." Which reasons? Known size in compile time and using heap sounds opposite to me.

Comment: @Klaus known big size is as good reason as any to place an array to dynamic memory

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `unique_ptr` that holds a raw array:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[][Y]> p(new int[X][Y]);
```

However, this doesn't give you meaningful bounds checking on the first axis, nor does it let you iterate using range-based for.

---

You could use a `unique_ptr` that holds a `std::array`

```
std::unique_ptr<std::array<std::array<int, Y>, X>> p;
```

However, this doesn't let you index, since `operator[]` is only defined for raw arrays.

---

I would just write my own wrapper that gives me the best of both. Something like:

```
template <typename T, size_t X, size_t Y>
struct Array {
    Array() {
        p.reset(new T[X][Y]);
    }   

    using row = T[Y];

    row* begin() { return p.get(); }
    row* end() { return p.get() + X; }

    row& operator[](size_t y) { return p[y]; }

    std::unique_ptr<int[][Y]> p;
};
```

Comment: Note that data in nested `std::array`'s are _not_ guaranteed to be contiguous (https://stackoverflow.com/q/9762662/873025).