# Is the data in nested std::arrays guaranteed to be contiguous post c++17?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, c++17, stdarray

I am using a nested `std::array`, and wonder if it is possible to use `memcpy` on it in order to copy the content of one array to the other as sketched below:

```cpp
std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 5> arr;
std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 5> arr2;
memcpy(&arr[0], &arr2[0], sizeof(int) * 25);
```

Since `C++17`, a C++ array is a [ContiguousContainer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ContiguousContainer); however, I think that the question if padding bytes can be placed at the end of an array (which is basically inside the memory chunk in a nested array) are unaffected by this property.

Is the data in `std::array<std::array<T,N>, M>` guaranteed to be contiguous?
Or does the answer to [this pre-c++17 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762662/is-the-data-in-nested-stdarrays-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous) still hold?

Comment: afaik `std::array` was already a contiguous container but the concept `ContiguousContainer` was introduced in C++17, so basically nothing changed

Comment: note that also `std::vector` is a ContiguousContainer since C++17, but that didnt mean that anything on `std::vector` had to change

Comment: Okay thanks :) I think then I'll close this question as duplicate of the pre-17 question